# Howto clean Photo Folder

Tags: photos, folders, macos

I opened Photo. I deleted all the pictures. Then I emptied the "Deleted images".

My Photo app is apparently empty.

I open finder, the photo library package is around 7GB an subfolders are full of old images and other unknown files.

I wish to clean all, to gain a fresh empty Library.

If I delete the .photoslibrary folder, the app shows an error message.

Can someone tell me the right procedure, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new library by opening iPhoto whilst holding <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd>. This creates a fresh iPhoto library which you can import media into.